# How can I configure a BIML element for attunity Oracle connector?

Tags: ssis, database-connection, biml, attunity

I read from [Using the Attunity Oracle Connector with Biml](http://www.bimlscript.com/Walkthrough/Details/67) a way to define an element for Attune Oracle connector by using CustomSsisConnection element . It's different from the actual connection definition in place in the project connection I have to work with. The current Attunity connector definition is defined by a DTS:ConnectionManager element, in which I change values to @@@@@@ for security reasons:

```
    <DTS:ConnectionManager xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
      DTS:ObjectName="Oracle_TVIA"
      DTS:DTSID="{608D9C98-CC33-4EC7-BF35-DDDB7BDBDBC7}"
      DTS:CreationName="MSORA">
      <DTS:PropertyExpression
        DTS:Name="ConnectionString">@[$Project::Oracle_Connector]
    </DTS:PropertyExpression>
      <DTS:ObjectData>
        <OracleXMLPackage>
          <OraConnectionString>SERVER=@@@@@@;USERNAME=
    @@@@@@;ORACLEHOME=;ORACLEHOME64=;WINAUTH=0</OraConnectionString>
          <OraRetain>False</OraRetain>
          <OraInitialCatalog></OraInitialCatalog>
         <OraServerName>@@@@@@</OraServerName      
    <OraUserName>@@@@@@</OraUserName>
          <OraOracleHome></OraOracleHome>
          <OraOracleHome64></OraOracleHome64>
          <OraWinAuthentication>False</OraWinAuthentication>
         <OraEnableDetailedTracing>False</OraEnableDetailedTracing>
         <OraPassword
           Sensitive="1"
           p4:Salt="@@@@@@"
           p4:IV="@@@@@@" 
   xmlns:p4="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS">@@@@@@@@@@@@</OraPassword>
       </OracleXMLPackage>
     </DTS:ObjectData>
   </DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

Attunity's connection mentioned in post is:

```
<CustomSsisConnection Name="Oracle Connector 1" CreationName="MSORA" ObjectData="&lt;OracleXMLPackage&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraConnectionString&gt;SERVER=XXXX;USERNAME=username;ORACLEHOME=;ORACLEHOME64=;WINAUTH=0&lt;/OraConnectionString&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraRetain&gt;False&lt;/OraRetain&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraInitialCatalog&gt;&lt;/OraInitialCatalog&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraServerName&gt;ec2-107-20-117-195.compute-1.amazonaws.com&lt;/OraServerName&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraUserName&gt;username&lt;/OraUserName&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraOracleHome&gt;&lt;/OraOracleHome&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraOracleHome64&gt;&lt;/OraOracleHome64&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraWinAuthentication&gt;False&lt;/OraWinAuthentication&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraEnableDetailedTracing&gt;False&lt;/OraEnableDetailedTracing&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;OraPassword Sensitive=&quot;1&quot; Encrypted=&quot;1&quot;&gt;AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAm1Wd3JvvU0+cUJlVQyqnaAAAAAAIAAAARABUAFMAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAA6xkf97NyWpMZVJk8BfUfOAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAABcdn9bN864uL88pKlNCAlwYAAAAcbtMszBiQhegvc8dBJXJRRNt9xmQRe2pFAAAANMQTe7MVbECC97BJJ8QQO0KMUfc&lt;/OraPassword&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/OracleXMLPackage&gt;" />
```

When I attemp to add this code within Biml schema, I got an compilation error message telling DTS:ConnectionManager is not a valid child of Biml.
Would you please advise how would I convert the DTS:ConnectionManager's definition to CustomSsisConnection's.

Thanks

The code generated by XSLT is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <Connection Name="Oracle_TVIA" ConnectionString="SERVER=@@@@@@;USERNAME=@@@@@@;ORACLEHOME=;ORACLEHOME64=;WINAUTH=0" />
        <Connection Name="Target_SQLBIPRO" ConnectionString="Data Source=SQLBIDES;Initial Catalog=TVIA;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package ConstraintMode="Linear" Name="staging_AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY">
            <Tasks>
                <ExecuteSQL Name="Truncate_AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY" ConnectionName="Target_SQLBIPRO">
                    <DirectInput>"exec dbo.delete_AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY ?,?"</DirectInput>
                </ExecuteSQL>
                <Dataflow Name="Load_AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY">
                    <PrecedenceConstraints>
                        <Inputs>
                            <Input OutputPathName="Truncate_AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY.Output" />
                        </Inputs>
                    </PrecedenceConstraints>
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource Name="Source_AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY" ConnectionName="Oracle_TVIA">
                            <ExternalTableInput Table="AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY" />
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <OleDbDestination Name="Target_AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY" ConnectionName="Target_SQLBIPRO">
                            <InputPath OutputPathName="Source_AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY.Output" />
                            <ExternalTableOutput Table="Staging_BOS_VR_OWNER_AMS_CD_PAYMENT_CATEGORY" />
                        </OleDbDestination>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: You just need to swap in your connection data to the relevant parts, which it looks like you may not have done for all of them?  What is the actual `Biml` you have written so far?

Comment: I am generating a Biml code iteratively for a group of tables in a remote Oracle System, the which I need to copy to an SQL Server Staging database:

Comment: Please post the Biml code you have so far that includes this connection that isn't working.  Without it you will get very little help.